# all_proxy hang without sudo while using proxy in golang

Tags: go, ssl, curl, https, proxy

some of my computers' behavior are different when I using a proxy code by golang, with https. While http is always ok.

for example:
for some normal computer ( Mac )
the right one:

**all_proxy=ip:port curl -vv -k https://baidu.com**

---> it works

---

In some computer (also, Mac):

**all_proxy=ip:port curl -vv -k https://baidu.com**

```
* Uses proxy env variable all_proxy == 'ip:port'
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ip (ip) port port (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to baidu.com:443
> CONNECT baidu.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: baidu.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 07 May 2021 06:28:57 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* Ignoring Transfer-Encoding in CONNECT 200 response
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to baidu.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to baidu.com:443
```

--- >  it does not work ?!

*However, in this case, if I use sudo , it works!*

**sudo all_proxy=ip:port curl -vv -k https://baidu.com**

```
* Uses proxy env variable all_proxy == 'ip:port'
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ip (ip) port port (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to baidu.com:443
> CONNECT baidu.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: baidu.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 07 May 2021 06:27:18 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* Ignoring Transfer-Encoding in CONNECT 200 response
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CN; ST=\U5317\U4EAC\U5E02; O=BeiJing Baidu Netcom Science Technology Co., Ltd; CN=www.baidu.cn
*  start date: Jan 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Secure Site Pro CN CA G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: baidu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: bfe/1.0.8.18
< Date: Fri, 07 May 2021 06:27:18 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 161
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.baidu.com/
<
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>bfe/1.0.8.18</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host ip left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

----- I totally don't know why.

It seems hang on the first "HELLO" after the proxy connect to the target website and "HELLO" didn't send out.

this problem only occur if the proxy server is code by golang, if I use a proxy server code by python, it will work.

also, if the proxy server is on the same computer, it will work in localhost only:

`all_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080 curl -vv -k https://baidu.com` ---> work!

`all_proxy=192.168.0.1:8080 curl -vv -k https://baidu.com` ---> not work!

pls help.

Comment: What role does golang have here?

Comment: the proxy is wrote in golang